# What do this expression mean? (SetConsoleTextAttribute function in C)

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm in a the middle of creating a console based small game for our C programming class assignment and I decided to make it more presentable and unique by adding text colors and text backgrounds.

While I was on my quest searching for a solution, I've found this handy function that will do just the way I wanted for my project but the problem is that there is this part I do not understand:

```
WORD wColor = ((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
```

Where, `BackC` and `ForgC` are given integers and the data type `WORD` is just a typedef for an unsigned short int. Specifically, what I don't understand is the `((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F)` part. Can anyone help me with this? I know that I can just use the function but I really want to know how the function works...Thanks!

Here is the full source code (colorExample.c)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void SetColorAndBackground(int ForgC, int BackC);
int main()
{
    SetColorAndBackground(10,1);   //color value range 0 up-to 256
    printf("what is text background color \n");
    SetColorAndBackground(11,1);
    printf("how about this?");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void SetColorAndBackground(int ForgC, int BackC)
{
     WORD wColor = ((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), wColor);
     return;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForgC` and `BackC` are two values that can really only expand to take up of 4 bits each (you can tell this because they are being [bitwise ANDed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0x0F`, which clears all but the last 4 bits of the first operand).

So if we look at them as 8-bit wide values, they would be of the form

```
ForgC      0000xxxx
BackC      0000yyyy
```

Then you bitwise shift `ForgC` 4 bits to the left, making

```
ForgC      xxxx0000
BackC      0000yyyy
```

And then you add them together¹, making

```
ForgC      xxxx0000
BackC      0000yyyy
Result     xxxxyyyy
```

So what this does in effect is "combine" both values into one. `SetConsoleTextAttribute` might then separate them again, or it might use the combined value as-is.

---

¹ Technically this should be a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) instead of integer addition. Although in this specific case (where the two operands are guaranteed to not have an 1-bit in the same position) both operations will produce the same result, bitwise OR makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon! This is absolutely what I want to know. I never knew that I could use literal binaries in a C program...If you have time, it would be great if you put the "bitwise OR" version here....Thanks again :)

Comment: @Raven: There's nothing to it, it's just `((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) | (ForgC & 0x0F)` (`|` instead of `+`).

Answer (score 0):

If takes the lower 4 bits of each `BackC` and `ForgC` and joins them to get a 8 bit value.

```
((
    BackC & 0x0F     // take last 4 bits of BackC
 ) << 4)             // and shift 4 to the left
 + 
 (
    ForgC & 0x0F     // plus take last 4 bits of ForgC
 )
```

E.g. if `BackC` is `0b......abcd` and `ForgC` is `0b.....efgh` (both in binary representation) you'll get the value `0xabcdefgh`.

Comment: Thanks man. This is technically the same answer as the one above, but I choose the other for it's elaborated answer...Anyways, I appreciate your help :)