# C color text in terminal applications in windows

Tags: c, windows, cmd, command-prompt, textcolor

I know "textcolor();" is for C++ and i've seen methods for unix...
but is there way for windows also?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\ntest - C programming text color!");
    printf("\n--------------------------------");
    printf("\n\n\t\t-BREAK-\n\n");
    textcolor(15);
    printf("WHITE\n");
    textcolor(0);
    printf("BLACK\n");
    textcolor(4);
    printf("RED\n");
    textcolor(1);
    printf("BLUE\n");
    textcolor(2);
    printf("GREEN\n");
    textcolor(5);
    printf("MAGENTA\n");
    textcolor(14);
    printf("YELLOW\n");
    textcolor(3);
    printf("CYAN\n");
    textcolor(7);
    printf("LIGHT GRAY\n");
}
```

I can't find any anything on the net...
let's hope the good people from stack overflow can help :D

C please, not C++

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you want a C and Windows specific solution, I'd recommend using the `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` function in the Win32 API. You'll need to grab a handle to the console, and then pass it with the appropriate attributes.

As a simple example:

```
/* Change console text color, then restore it back to normal. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
    WORD saved_attributes;

    /* Save current attributes */
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &consoleInfo);
    saved_attributes = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("This is some nice COLORFUL text, isn't it?");

    /* Restore original attributes */
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_attributes);
    printf("Back to normal");

    return 0;
}
```

For more info on the available attributes, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great, just wondering how to set it back to the default light gray? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoeDF To do that you'll need to read in the original attributes with `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`, store them in a variable, and then restore them when done. I've updated the answer to show how to do this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx

You can see one usage of it right here on SO: [What do this expression mean? (SetConsoleTextAttribute function in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539614/what-do-this-expression-mean-setconsoletextattribute-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I add a simple script that just achieve this, some considerations:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>


void InitConsole()
{
    
    WORD wColor = (BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    HANDLE handleConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); /* Handle to current output buffer*/
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleBuffer;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(handleConsole, wColor);
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handleConsole, &consoleBuffer))
        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(handleConsole, consoleBuffer.wAttributes, consoleBuffer.dwSize.X * consoleBuffer.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    
    return;
}   


int main() 
{
    InitConsole();
    SetConsoleTitle("Mini Desktop App"); 
    while(1){
        printf("Works as expected\n");
        printf("Press any Key to exit :)\n");
        getch();
        break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

### Using Defined Arguments

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>


void InitConsole(int ForgC, int BackC)
{
    WORD wColor = ((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
    HANDLE handleConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); /* Handle to current output buffer*/
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleBuffer;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(handleConsole, wColor);
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handleConsole, &consoleBuffer))
        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(handleConsole, consoleBuffer.wAttributes, consoleBuffer.dwSize.X * consoleBuffer.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    
    return;
}   
    


int main() 
{
    InitConsole(15, 1);
    SetConsoleTitle("Mini Desktop App"); 
    while(1){
        printf("Works as expected\n");
        printf("Press any Key to exit :)\n");
        getch();
        break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

### Documentation

- [character-attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes)
- Information about a console screen buffer [CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffer-info-str).
- To determine the current color attributes of a screen buffer, call the [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) function.
- Sets the character attributes for a specified number of character cells, beginning at the specified coordinates in a screen buffer --> [FillConsoleOutputAttribute function](http://FillConsoleOutputAttribute%20function)

Answer (score 0):

TWO WAYS EASY
1: Console colors( Console Screen Buffer ) > easy to use by microsoft doc.
[ConsoleScreenBuffer⭐⭐⭐](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers?redirectedfrom=MSDN#_win32_character_attributes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* Console colors only RGB(Red, Green, Blue, Normal) */

int main() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
    WORD saved_attributes;

/* Save current attributes */
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &consoleInfo);
    saved_attributes = consoleInfo.wAttributes;
    
    
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("This is some nice BLUE text, isn't it?\n");
    
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);
    printf("This is some nice RED text, isn't it?\n");
    
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    printf("This is some nice GREEN text, isn't it?");
    
/* Restore original attributes */
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_attributes);
    printf("\nBack to normal");
        
    return 0;
}
```

2: ANSI colors
[ANSI Colors⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=5270)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AC_BLACK "\x1b[30m"
#define AC_RED "\x1b[31m"
#define AC_GREEN "\x1b[32m"
#define AC_YELLOW "\x1b[33m"
#define AC_BLUE "\x1b[34m"
#define AC_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define AC_CYAN "\x1b[36m"
#define AC_WHITE "\x1b[37m"
#define AC_NORMAL "\x1b[m"

int main()
{
    printf("Color test:\n");
    printf("%sThis is red text %s\n",AC_RED, AC_NORMAL);
    printf("%sThis is green text %s\n",AC_GREEN, AC_NORMAL);
    printf("%sThis is blue text %s\n",AC_BLUE, AC_NORMAL);
    printf("%sThis is yellow text %s\n",AC_YELLOW, AC_NORMAL);
    // AC_NORMAL to default color...
    printf("\nANSII COLORS 8\n");
    printf("End test\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).