# Applying color to a specific element in an array in C

Tags: c, colors

Is there a way to color just one element in an array?

Say, I have a 2D array like this:

```
main ()
{
int x,y;
char arr[3][3];
for (x=0;x<3;x++) 
for (y=0;y<3;y++) 
 arr[x][y]='a';

arr[1][1]='b';
for (x=0;x<3;x++) 
for (y=0;y<3;y++)
printf("%c", arr[x][y]);
}
```

How to apply a color to only character 'b' located at  arr [1][1]?

Comment: Color an element? :/

Comment: Do you mean a color code like `#ffffff` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [stdlib and colored output in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c)

Comment: Note that depending on the nature of the console on which you want to print colored characters, the method might differ.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. This one's for Windows. If you have the same situation as I do, here's how I did it. 
I used the SetConsoleTextAttribute() function, thanks to good answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203362/c-color-text-in-terminal-applications-in-windows)

so my code was

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main
{
enter code here
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
WORD saved_attributes;
char arr[3][3];
for (x=0;x<3;x++) 
for (y=0;y<3;y++) 
arr[x][y]='a';
arr[1][1]='b';
for (x=0;x<3;x++)
for (y=0;y<3;y++)
{
if (arr[x][y]=='b')
{
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);
printf("%c", arr[x][y]);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_attributes);
}
else 
{
printf("%c", arr[x][y]);
}
}
```