# In Rust, how can I capture process output with colors?

Tags: terminal, console, rust, tty, windows-console

I would like to capture output from another process (for example `git status`), process it, and print with all styles (bold, italics, underscore) and colors. It's very important for me to further process that `String`, I **don't** want only to print it.

In the Unix world, I think this would involve escape codes, I'm not sure about Windows world but it's important for me too.

I know how to do it without colors:

```
fn exec_git() -> String {
    let output = Command::new("git")
        .arg("status")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");

    String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).into_owned()
}
```

Maybe I should use `spawn` instead?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to fool `git` into thinking it is outputting to a terminal (and thus colorize its output) or are you content with simply passing a flag/configuration to git that will force it to use colors without relying on terminal detection?

Comment: Fooling `git` seems to be nice idea.
Right now `git` checks if stream is TTY right?
(something like `if (uv_guess_handle(1) == UV_TTY) ` in libuv)

Ok - let's assume I'll fool it (don't know how yet, but I'll solve that sooner or later). Then my output will contain escape codes and printing them will color final output?

Comment: If you manage to fool git, yes your output should be colorized (if it's colorized on a terminal), however that's probably the most difficult option and I am not quite sure *how* you can do so.

Comment: AFAIK, this simply cannot be done on Windows in the console.

Comment: @WojciechPolak I suggest you ask this question with different tags, maybe windows-console, console, terminal. Then when you get a generic solution you could post another question on how to translate it to Rust. The gist of the question isn't specific to Rust and I'd wager there's a lot of experts on stackoverflow that only monitor specific tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code **already works**:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("ls")
        .args(&["-l", "--color"])
        .env("LS_COLORS", "rs=0:di=38;5;27:mh=44;38;5;15")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute");

    let sout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).expect("Not UTF-8");
    let serr = String::from_utf8(output.stderr).expect("Not UTF-8");

    println!("{}", sout);
    println!("{}", serr);
}
```

Prints the output:

```
total 68
-rw-r--r-- 4 root root 56158 Dec 23 00:00 [0m[44;38;5;15mCargo.lock[0m
-rw-rw-r-- 4 root root  2093 Dec  9 02:54 [44;38;5;15mCargo.toml[0m
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Dec 30 15:24 [38;5;27msrc[0m
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Dec 23 00:19 [38;5;27mtarget[0m
```

Note that there's a bunch of junk scattered inside the output (`[44;`, `[0m`, etc.). Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and the terminal emulator interprets those to change the color of the following text.

If you print the string with debugging, you will see:

```
\u{1b}[0m\u{1b}[44;38;5;15mCargo.lock\u{1b}[0m
```

Each escape code starts with an `ESC` (`\u{1b}`) followed by the actual command. You will have to parse those in order to ignore them for whatever processing you are doing.

Windows does not use escape codes (although [maybe it can in Windows 10](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2016/02/04/Windows-10-TH2-(v1511)-Console-Host-Enhancements)?), and instead a program directly [modifies the console it is connected to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203489/155423). There is nothing in the output to indicate the color.

Answer (score 2):

You can force git to output colors by using `git -c color.status=always status`

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("git")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("color.status=always")
        .arg("status")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");

    let output = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).into_owned();

    println!("{}", output);
}
```

This works for `git status` only. For a more general solution, you either have to check the programs documentation and hope there is a way to force colored output or check how the program determines if it should output colors or not (such as checking for the `COLORTERM` environment variable).