# How to make text colored in c lang in cmd?

Tags: c

how to make text colored in c lang?
The example is given in the image included.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C color text in terminal applications in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203362/c-color-text-in-terminal-applications-in-windows)

Comment: Avoid links. Display your image directly and show us what you have done so far

Comment: Are you on linux, windows or mac? Do you need a library?

Comment: [some code](https://github.com/Zirias/pocas/blob/master/src/lib/core/textcolor_win32.c) -- just to get an idea what one COULD do.

Comment: @Badda [new users can only link images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267491/208223). if you would have prefered an embeded image, you can suggest and edit to the question. Certainly OP should show what he has tried. Jivtesh Chahal see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44203371/edit) your question.

Answer (score 2):

This may be realised via ANSI escape sequences, although the effect depends on the terminal application used. For example to change the text to red use:

```
puts("\033[31m");
```

For further information visit Wikipedia, which has decent [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for all codes.